# How to apply X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test for Feature Importance and return quality metrics?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to test a few feature importance models on my dataset. I am using filter methods, embedded methods, and wrapper methods. I have the following questions:

1) Filter methods(chi-squared, Pearson Correlation): Is it correct that I shall only apply X and y since the concept of the splitting of train and test does not apply for filter methods?

2) For embedded and wrapper methods, I only found examples which use X_train, y_train in the model but do not use X_test, y_test (including cross validation) along with quality or significance measures of the features. This is an example:

```
X = df.drop(['id', 'target'], axis=1)    
y = df['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

#Random Forest for FEATURE IMPORTANCE
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

embeded_rf_selector = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))
embeded_rf_selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
embeded_rf_support = embeded_rf_selector.get_support()
embeded_rf_feature = X_train.loc[:,embeded_rf_support].columns.tolist()
```

How do I apply the model for feature importance to the TEST data set (with cross validation) along with a metric of quality or weight of the features? Also, as of now I am going through the Feature Importance models one-by-one. Therfore, I would appreciate very much if anyone can refer a great pipeline script for such task.

Thanks!

Comment: look into SHAP https://github.com/slundberg/shap